# Paperless Environment

Tags: open-source

my company is planning to go for paperless, what free open source software do I need to help pull it off? All suggestions are welcome, We all ready have citrix cloud stack on premise if that helps.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic, as per the FAQ.

Comment: "Paperless office" is really a marketing term. You/your company might start its journey by banning the use of that kind of talk, & start defining exactly what you mean in terms of the day to day operations that staff there have to carry out. This will move you towards actually having an actionable list of items, as opposed to a meaningless mission statement. This will tell you if there is a need to send (for example) legal letters in postal mail as per t1nt1n's comments, & it will also show you if there are any obvious "wins", e.g. company newsletter that can easily become a company intranet.

Comment: Your comapany lives a dream. When it wakes up it liost moeny or is bankrupt. Paperless wont work - if for anything then for a lot of LEGAL reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to answer in its current format, we do not know if you use a CRM/ERP. Emails etc etc.

But you need to look at where the paper is generated. You cant just install a single app and think that all paper will go!

We run a paperless office but I can tell you we still have paper in the office. Clients still send things in and certain things NEED to be printed **by law**.

My suggestion would be take a step back, look where things are being generated is it needed? Is it just easier for the user, could they have a little training to help? look at the applications that you have in house and sit down with users and ask why the print it. We found a number of people didn’t know they could save email text into our CRM so printed it out and scanned it in! After training we cut our print count by around 2000 pages  a month.